# Move element in catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml to bundle summary

Tags: magento2

I want to move my plugin element position for bundle product page

[image]

I tried various ways but couldn't achieve it.

Here is my catalog_product_view.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
  <block class="My\Example\Block\Catalog\Sampledata" name="my.example.block" after="product.info.price" template="My_Example::sample/product.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

And, here is my catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml

```
<move element="my.example.block" destination="bundle.options.container" after="product.info.addtocart.bundle"/>
```

Also I have tried different ways like

```
 1. <move element="my.example.block" destination="bundle.options.container" after="bundle.summary"/>
 2. <move element="my.example.block" destination="bundle.options.container" after="product.info"/>
 3. <move element="my.example.block" destination="bundle.options.container"  after="product.price.render.bundle.customization"/>
```

None of those were working.
Can you please help me how I can move my element after customized price block?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring wrong block name, can use:

```
<move element="my.example.block" destination="bundle.summary"/>
```

Hope above will help!